# If $G$ is a free abelian group of finite rank, then $G/H$ is finite if and only if the ranks of $G$ and $H$ are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am studying the theorem:

> Let $G$ be a free abelian group of rank $r$ and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Then $G/H$ is finite if and only if the ranks of $G$ and $H$ are equal.

Let $H$ have rank $s$, I know how to choose $\mathbb{Z}$-bases $u_1,\ldots, u_r$ of $G$ and $v_1, \ldots, v_s$ of $H$ with $v_i = a_iu_i$.

I do not understand why the quotient group $G/H$ is the direct product of finite cyclic groups of orders $a_1, \ldots, a_s$ and $r-s$ infinite cyclic groups.

May you help me please?

Comment: The quotient group is denoted $ G/H $ as opposed to $ G \setminus H $ which represents set complement / set minus.

Comment: Do you understand a case like $G=\Bbb{Z}^2$, $H=\langle(3,0),(0,5)\rangle$, when $G/H\simeq \Bbb{Z}_3\oplus \Bbb{Z}_5$?

Comment: @Jurki Lahtonen I think that I understand that case. Now, since G is a free abelian group of rank n, it is isomorphic to Z^r (the direct product of r copies of the additive of integers), while its subgroup H is isomorphic to the group a_1Z x a_2Z x ... x a_sZ. This means that G/H is isomorphic to Z^r/a_1Z x a_2Z x ... x a_sZ ( why is this a product of finite cyclic group of orders a_1, a_2 , ...  a_s and r-s infinite cyclic groups?).

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume, more generally, that $G$ is finitely generated (not necessarily free).

Consider the exact sequence $0\to H\to G\to G/H\to0$ and apply to it the exact functor $\def\TQ{\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}}{-}\TQ$, getting the exact sequence of vector spaces
$$
0\to H\TQ\to G\TQ\to(G/H)\TQ\to0
$$
Since the rank of $G$ is the same as the dimension of $G\TQ$, we have that the rank of $H$ is the same as the rank of $G$ if and only if $(G/H)\TQ=0$.

Since $G'=G/H$ is finitely generated, the [fundamental theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification) says that $G'\cong t(G')\oplus(G'/t(G'))$, where $t(G')$ is the torsion part, which is finite. Now $G'\TQ=0$ if and only if $G'/t(G')=0$, that is, when $G'$ is torsion.

A finitely generated abelian group is finite if and only if it is torsion, again by the fundamental theorem.