# Showing that the factor group $G/K$ is finite given arbitrary abelian groups $G$ and $H$ and a condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

We are given the condition that $G$ is torsion-free and has rank $r$, and $K\leq G$ also has rank $r$. (Recall that $G$ is abelian.)

Can it be shown that $G/K$ is finite? I'm thinking that we can use the fact that $\textit{if}$ $G$ is finitely generated (and so has a basis of $r$ elements), its torsion part is finite -- then perhaps an epimorphism could be set up from $G$ to its torsion part $t(G)$ with kernel $K$ so that we can apply the First Isomorphism Theorem. But I don't know what that epimorphism would be or how we can show $G$ to be finitely generated. So this approach seems like a bad one.

A similar question was asked here: [If $G$ is a free abelian group of finite rank, then $G/H$ is finite if and only if the ranks of $G$ and $H$ are equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2186822/if-g-is-a-free-abelian-group-of-finite-rank-then-g-h-is-finite-if-and-only) but received no answer.

EDIT: A counter-example has been provided in the comments.

Comment: Without finitely generated, consider $G=\Bbb Q$, $K=\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I provided an answer to the linked question, generalizing it to your setup.

Comment: @egreg The problem is we can't assume that $G$ is finitely generated.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's an easy counter-example, thanks.

Comment: @SPS Indeed, Hagen’s example shows that finitely generated is necessary for concluding finiteness of $G/K$.